# sql where clause query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I imported a few xml files into my database. I have multiple survery ID's and multiple varname's per survey each with a value.

I have been able to get the results i need but i am not sure if i am doing this correctly.
I am not entirely sure how i would write a query to select out desired survey ids..

```
where varname in ('age') and value >18
```

would give me all survey ids with participants older than 18

but what if i have multiple variables and some are numbers...so i cant just write >18 if i have other variables that are numbers too...

how can i associate the value to that varname?

```
SURVEY_ID   VARNAME VALUE
674078265   PROVID  provider name
674078265   SEX Female
674078265   age 55
674078265   SP  Internal Med
674078265   ID# 12345
674111111   ADJSAMP Included
674111111   PROVID  provider name2
674111111   SEX Male
674111111   age 34
674111111   SP  Surgery
674111111   ADJSAMP Included
674111111   ID# 6789
```

Comment: What datatype is the value column?

Comment: Welcome to the world of EAV (Entity Attribute Value) tables!  Depending on overall setup, you may be able to further normalize this, but surveys are one of the areas where it's likely to be useful.  If you can, I'd recommend creating a `VARNAME` table, so you don't get entries like `'age'`, `'Age'`, `'AGE'`, `'age' = "none of your #!*& business!"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName 
WHERE SURVEY_ID IN (SELECT SURVEY_ID
                    FROM TableName
                    WHERE VARNAME = 'age'
                    AND VALUE > 18)
```

Or a more efficient way will be

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TableName 
              WHERE SURVEY_ID = t.SURVEY_ID
              AND VARNAME = 'age'
              AND VALUE > 18)
```

OR

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TABLE_Name t1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_Name t2
ON t1.SURVEY_ID = t2.SURVEY_ID
WHERE t2.VARNAME = 'age' 
AND   t2.VALUE > 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending @M.Ali answer to actually answer your question - add as many exists as you need for all field conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM TableName 
          WHERE SURVEY_ID = t.SURVEY_ID
          AND VARNAME = 'age'
          AND VALUE > 18)
  and EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM TableName 
          WHERE SURVEY_ID = t.SURVEY_ID
          AND VARNAME = 'sex'
          AND VALUE = 'Male')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually offer a blend of the two answers, and not just an query, but why.

It appears you want ALL elements associated for a given survey provided it met a specific criteria you were looking for... This, I would give credit for M.Ali's FIRST answer, but second based on multiple criteria you may be interested in.

But then, for further analysis of the data, the multiple records per survey might not be practicle... Instead, I would go with a cross-tab result.  TO QUALIFY the records, it would be an optimized.

First, start with the simple query to get surveys that qualify multiple criteria.  I would have an index on the table on all three fields in this case ( SURVEY_ID, VARNAME, VALUE )

```
SELECT 
      s1.*
   FROM 
      YourTable s1
         JOIN ( SELECT s2.SURVEY_ID
                           FROM YourTable s2

                              JOIN YourTable s3
                                 on s2.survey_id = s3.survey_id
                                 AND s3.varname = 'SEX'
                                 AND s3.value = 'Male'

                              JOIN YourTable s4
                                 on s2.survey_id = s4.survey_id
                                 AND s3.varname = 'ADJSAMP'
                                 AND s3.value = 'Included'

                          WHERE s2.VARNAME = 'age'
                            AND s2.VALUE > 18 ) PreQual
         on s1.SURVEY_ID = PreQual.Survey_ID
```

So, the inner query, you can swap the criteria in either way, and add additional joins for more criteria (or less).  Whatever you suspect would be the smallest result criteria, I would put where the "age" > 18 where clause is, and adjust the others.

So, the inner query first starts getting those where age > 18, by adding the additional join (alias s3) on the same survey ID, but different criteria is almost like putting the columns side-by-side for analysis.  If they don't exist, the entire survey would be ignored.  Once qualified survey IDs are found, that is joined to the master table to get ALL row elements.

Now, to make it more manageable.  Putting into a cross-tab on each column.  Just change the select fields criteria and add a GROUP BY for the survey ID, but the rest of the query would remain intact.

```
SELECT 
      s1.survey_id,
      max( case when varname = 'PROVID' then value end ) as Provider,
      max( case when varname = 'SEX' then value end ) as Gender,
      max( case when varname = 'age' then value end ) as Age,
      max( case when varname = 'SP' then value end ) as Specialty,
      max( case when varname = 'ID#' then value end ) as IDNumber,
      max( case when varname = 'ADJSAMP' then value end ) as AdjustSample
   FROM
      [rest of original query sample above]
   GROUP BY
      s1.survey_id
```

Now, if you did not apply any criteria filtering, the above query would give you results something like...

```
survey_id  Provider        Gender  Age  Specialty     IDNumber  AdjustSample
674078265  provider name   Female  55   Internal Med  12345     Included
674111111  provider name2  Male    34   Surgery       6789      Included
```

Comment: This is all extremely useful. I actually only need the survey ID that qualify so i can then run additional queries with that subset. Thank you everyone!

Comment: @user3101182, you could also take your input, build the final cross-tab query ONCE, then just have simple criteria directly against the column names instead of the complex joins.  Probably a much better solution for you.